# When she said that she loves or loved

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, backshifting, reported-speech

Which one of these two sentences is correct?

1. > When she said that she loved me
2. > When she said that she loves me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are good, depending on the situation.

If you are unsure whether she *still* loves you, or you know she *doesn't* anymore, or she was *lying*(and you know it), you should say **loved**.

If

> She loves me

is still true, you can say **loves**.

You can find more infos [here](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/), basically:

*You do not need to change the tense if the reporting verb is in the present, or if the original statement was about something that is still true.*